# Mod Rewrite Regex - Match a url containting A but not B

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, front-controller

I'm trying to send page requested through a front controller.

I need to match the following urls

```
domain.com/admin/
domain.com/admin/somepage
```

but I also have some assets in the /admin subfolder that I DONT want to match

```
domain.com/assets
domain.com/assets/mything.css
domain.com/assets/mything.css
domain.com/xml/myxml.xml
```

I have written the following rule (inside .htaccess in the root of the site and that works for all 5 example URLs. How do I get it to match the top two ONLY?)

```
RewriteBase / 
# index.php is the front controller
RewriteRule ^(admin) admin/index.php [L,QSA]
```

There are two ways I can see of doing this (I'd like to know how to do it using the folder 'assets' and 'xml' as an exclusion AND by setting extensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a negative [RewriteCond](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) before the final routing rule along these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !assets
```

Comment: Thanks - this works but it also matches something like domain.com/admin/something/something/assets. I would only like to match /assets if it comes directly after the '/admin' - is this possible?